# dplyr filter issue with %in%

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a list of records and trying to keep the four records out of my final result. I have created a filtered variable below and used the following code to get the results. The code runs but instead of filtering out 4 records it only filters two records and the last two records in the filter variable remain in the final result. what could I be doing wrong?

```
filtered <-
  c(
    "Foundation1 - X",
    "Foundation2 - XX",
    "Y19 Success  - XXX",
  "Funda<f3>n Prof - XXX")

live_adjusted <- live %>%
dplyr::filter(!name%in%filtered)
```

Comment: can you post a representative sample of your data? 
You can use `dput(live)` and post the result inside your question.
Otherwise it will be difficult to help you on this particular problem. I would guess that it is an issue of spelling.

Comment: thank you Cettt, you are right, there were some weird spelling/spacing issues,  which I fixed, and then the code worked:)